# Swift Could Not Cast Value of Type __NSInlineData to PFFile

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to display my Parse users image in a tableview cell and I run into an error when I try to pull the image

```
Could not cast value of type '_NSInlineData' (0x1086e9cf8) to 'PFFile' (0x106b2ee80)
```

I'm trying to figure out whether this is a result of how I'm trying to get the data or the format that the image file is saved in.

Here is how the image is being saved,

UserRegistrationViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class UserRegistrationViewController: UIViewController {


    func displayAlert(title:String, error:String) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
            action in



        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    @IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var profileImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        var FBSession = PFFacebookUtils.session()

        var accessToken = FBSession.accessTokenData.accessToken

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token="+accessToken)

        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                response, data, error in

                let image = UIImage(data: data)

                self.profileImage.image = image


                user["image"] = data

                user.saveInBackground()
        })

        FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({
            connection, result, error in

            user["name"] = result["name"]

            user.saveInBackground()

            println(result)

        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func registerUser(sender: AnyObject) {

        var error = ""

        if usernameTextField.text == nil || emailTextField.text == nil || passwordTextField.text == nil {

            error = "Please enter a username, email and password"

        }


        if error != "" {

            displayAlert("Error In Form", error: error)

        } else {

            var user = PFUser.currentUser()

            user.username = usernameTextField.text
            user.password = passwordTextField.text
            user.email = emailTextField.text



            user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in
                if signupError == nil {

                    println(user.username)
                    println(user.password)
                    println(user.email)


                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("successfulRegistration", sender: self)

                    /*self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)*/

                } else {

                    if let errorString = signupError.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
                        error = errorString as String
                    } else {

                        error = "Please try again later."

                    }


                    self.displayAlert("Could Not Sign Up", error: error)

                }
            }


        }


    }

}
```

Here is how I am trying to pull and display the data:

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    var userArray : NSMutableArray = []


    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        loadParseData()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func loadParseData() {

        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {

                    println("\(objects.count) users are listed")

                    for object in objects {

                        self.userArray.addObject(object)

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("There is an error")
            }
        }
    }



    let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.userArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        var individualUser = userArray[row] as! PFUser
        var username = individualUser.username as String

        var profilePicture = individualUser["image"] as! PFFile

        profilePicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (result, error) in

            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: result)



        })


        cell.usernameLabel.text = username

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func finishAddingUsers(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("finishAddingUsers", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save data to a `PFFile`, use any of these methods:

```
+ fileWithData:

+ fileWithName:data:

+ fileWithName:contentsAtPath:

+ fileWithName:data:contentType:

+ fileWithData:contentType:
```

What you're doing is you're setting a PFFile instance to an NSData instance, when what you're actually trying to do is setting the *data* of the PFFile instance to NSData instance

Comment: thanks for the answer and you are specifically referencing where I'm calling `user["image"] = data` and saving it in background?

Comment: I think it might be related to the data format that the image is saved in. I noticed in my database that my "image" is being saved in a `Bytes` format as opposed to `File` format that is show in documentation. Do my thoughts align with yours?

Comment: @cphill Have you tried doing `user["image"] = [PFFile fileWithData:data];`?

Comment: I believe that is an Obj-C class reference and not swift. When I try something like `PFFIle(` I'm given types like `(data: NSData!)` and `(data: NSData!, contentType: String)`, but nothing related to `fileWithData`

Comment: @cphill `PFFile(data: data)`.

Comment: hey @Schemetrical, sorry that this is still ongoing and I appreciate the help, but when I set `user["image"] = PFFile(data: data)` in `UserRegistrationViewController.swift` I get an error from Parse saying: `[Error]: invalid type for key image, expected bytes, but got file (Code: 111, Version: 1.6.3)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @cphill huh. And data throws an error... I'm not quite sure any more, I'll upvote your question for visibility. Another possibility is that the error isn't where I thought it was.

Comment: nevermind! I figured it out and thank you so much for your help. The last bit was key and the error was related to the fact that my data table had "image" established as Bytes format from previous tests. Since you are not able to programmatically change the data format for a column once its established, I kept receiving the errors. I created a new column and it was saved in the proper `File` data format. Thanks again!